# Let $S=\{( x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}\mid xy>1\}$, show that $S$ is open

Tags: general-topology

> Let $S=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}\mid xy>1\}$.
>   Show that $S$ is open.

Please step by step

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just two steps:

1. the map $f\colon\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x,y)=xy$ is continuous;
2. $S$ is the inverse image under $f$ of $(1,\infty)$, which is open in $\mathbb{R}$.